# Got javascript error but can't find where the code is in chrome's developer tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, developer-tools, google-developer-tools

My website http://a.nycweb.io has this javascript after loading, by clicking the error, I only find a blank line, as shown in picture:
[image]

How am I supposed to debug this?

**UPDATE**
I actually found the code from Safari's developer tool, in which when I click the error, the line in question properly shows up.
Is this some bug with Chrome's dev tool?

Comment: Search the script for where the property top gets read?

Comment: I get no error in the console after loading the page